# Select only unique ids row of table with different values in Descending order

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mysql-select-db

I'm trying to get data that have the same medicine_id and unique insurance_id and last inserted row. Put Group by and Order by but in that got random data not last inserted.
I tried this code but got not last inserted data

```
SELECT
    `m1`.`*`
FROM
    (
        `pricings` `m1`
    LEFT JOIN `pricings` `m2` ON
        (
            (
                (
                    `m1`.`medicine_id` = `m2`.`medicine_id`
                )
            )
        )
    )
     WHERE m1.medicine_id = 2
    group BY m1.insurance_id DESC
    ORDER BY m1.created_at;
```

Here are the total rows.
**This is a full table**

| id | medicine_id | insurance_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4311 | 2 | 1 | 2021-04-12 16:05:07 |
| 4766 | 2 | 1 | 2022-01-15 11:56:06 |
| 4767 | 2 | 38 | 2021-05-12 08:17:11 |
| 7177 | 2 | 38 | 2022-03-30 10:14:11 |
| 4313 | 2 | 39 | 2021-04-12 16:05:46 |
| 4768 | 2 | 39 | 2021-05-12 08:17:30 |
| 1356 | 2 | 40 | 2020-11-02 11:25:43 |
| 3764 | 2 | 40 | 2021-03-08 15:42:16 |
| 4769 | 2 | 40 | 2021-05-12 08:17:44 |

**And I want to like this**

| id | medicine_id | insurance_id | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4766 | 2 | 1 | 2022-01-15 11:56:06 |
| 4768 | 2 | 39 | 2021-05-12 08:17:30 |
| 4769 | 2 | 40 | 2021-05-12 08:17:44 |
| 7177 | 2 | 38 | 2022-03-30 10:14:11 |

Comment: Please don't put images. Share sample data, expected output and what have you tried so far.

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Please also show your attempt at the sql

Comment: for this you would need to expand your where  statement 

Where  m1.medicine_id = 2  and  m1.insurance_id in ("Here add the ids you need separated with comma")

and in your select, select MAX(created_at)

Comment: Which version of MySQL?  MySQL 5.x doesn't have `ROW_NUMBER()` or other window functions that will solve this for you more neatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL 5.x: Use a sub-query to find the max created_at value per group, then join that on the source table to identify the row it was from.

```
SELECT
  p.`*`
FROM
  `pricings`   p
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    `medicine_id`,
    `insurance_id`,
    MAX(created_at)   AS `created_at`
  FROM
    `pricings`
  GROUP BY
    `medicine_id`,
    `insurance_id`
)
  p_max
    ON  p.`medicine_id`  = p_max.`medicine_id`
    AND p.`insurance_id` = p_max.`insurance_id`
    AND p.`created_at`   = p_max.`created_at`
WHERE
  p.`medicine_id` = 2
ORDER BY
  p.`created_at`;
```

MySQL 8: Use `ROW_NUMBER()` to enumerate each group, then pick the first row from each group.

```
SELECT
  p.`*`
FROM
  `pricings`   p
FROM
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY `medicine_id`,
                   `insurance_id`
          ORDER BY `created_at` DESC
    )
      AS `row_id`
  FROM
    `pricings`
)
  p
WHERE
      p.`medicine_id` = 2
  AND p.`row_id`      = 1
ORDER BY
  p.`created_at`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding it as an answer as well.  I have not tested it, just fix the formating to work with whatever version of databse you are working with and let me know of the results.

```
SELECT m1.id  , m1.Insurance_id , m1.medicine_id , max(m1,created_at)
FROM (
    `pricings` `m1` LEFT JOIN `pricings` `m2` ON `m1`.`medicine_id` = `m2`.`medicine_id`
    )
WHERE m1.medicine_id = 2 and m1.insurance_id in (1,39,40,38)
GROUP BY m1.insurance_id DESC
ORDER BY m1.created_at;
```

Edit. I also removed the 6 extra parenthesis, I don't see how they could be of any use

Comment: getting created_at correct but id is not from that created_at row

Comment: this table has lots of rows so for some rows  used this **m1.medicine_id = 2**

Comment: Do you mean insurance Id?  this is because I have declared in WHERE clause that I only want the following Insurance_id  1,39,40,38 , If you don't need those ID's then remove the following - > and m1.insurance_id in (1,39,40,38)

Comment: not Insurance_id. I have many medicines but to check this I put medicine_id =2 so data is less so easy to manage